# Can´t reach laravel endpoints with Nginx (Windows)

Tags: laravel, nginx, arduino, laragon

I´m trying to reach laravel endpoints with Nginx in Laragon and in Windows. I have an Arduino Leonardo connected to wifi by a wifishield, and it reaches the service but always the index.php page or 404 not found. I´ve tried all nginx configurations but none helped.
This is the arduino code for connecting the server:

```
void httpRequest() {
  client.stop();
  Serial.println("\nStarting connection to server...");
  if(client.connect(server, 8080)) {
    client.println("GET /api_terrarium/api/get-actuators");
   
    client.println("Connection: close");
    client.println();
    lastConnectionTime = millis();
  } else{
    Serial.println("connection failed");
  }
}
```

The nginx config files are:
Server file:

```
server {
    listen 8080;
    server_name api_terrarium.test *.api_terrarium.test;
    root "D:/laragon/www/api_terrarium/public/";
    
    index index.html index.htm index.php;
 
    #location / {
     #   try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
        #autoindex on;
    #}
    
    
    location ~ \.php$ {
        #try_files $uri /index.php =404;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass php_upstream;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
    
    
    charset utf-8;
    
    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}

# This file is auto-generated.
# If you want Laragon to respect your changes, just remove the [auto.] prefix
# If you want to use SSL, enable it at: Menu > Nginx > SSL > Enabled
```

Default conf:

```
server {
    listen 8080 default_server;
    server_name localhost ;
    root "/var/www/public";
    
    index index.html index.htm index.php;
 
    # Access Restrictions
    allow       127.0.0.1;
    allow all;
 
    include "D:/laragon/etc/nginx/alias/*.conf";

  location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        gzip_static on;
    }
    
    location ~ \.php$ {
        allow all;
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass php_upstream;      
        #fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }

    
    charset utf-8;
    
    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location ~ /\.ht {
        
    }
    
}
```

And the laravel web.php:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;


Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
Route::post('/add-new-parameter', [ 'uses'=>'ParametersController@addParameter']
);
Route::get('/get-parameter', ['uses'=>'ParametersController@getParameter']
);
Route::get('/get-historic', ['uses'=>'ParametersController@getHistoric']
);
Route::delete('/delete-historic', ['uses'=>'ParametersController@deleteHistoric']
);
Route::get('/get-actuators', ['uses'=>'ActuatorController@getActuators']
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Nginx didn´t get the api.conf and perma choose the default one, so in Nginx.conf I commented

```
include "D:/laragon/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*.conf";
```

and added

```
include "D:/laragon/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/api_terrarium.test.conf";
```